# Interpretation of Weinberg-Witten theorem

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, gravity, quantum-spin, quantum-gravity

The [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem#Theorem) states that

> *A 3 + 1D QFT quantum field theory with a conserved $4$-vector current $J^\mu$ which is Poincaré covariant does not admit massless particles with helicity  $|h| > 1/2$.*
>
> *A 3 + 1D QFT with a conserved stress–energy tensor $T^{\mu \nu}$ which is Poincaré covariant does not admit massless particles with helicity $|h| > 1$.*

This theorem is interpreted to mean that the graviton cannot be a composite particle. However, I do not quite follow this interpretation.

My understanding is that the massless graviton of spin $2$ *ought to have* a Poincare-covariant conserved stress-tensor (and Poincare-covariant conserved $4$-vector currents associated to other symmetries). So the Weinberg-Witten theorem means the graviton *is not allowed to exist at all*.

That the graviton is not allowed to be a composite particle appears to be a weaker conclusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [67998](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67998/).

Comment: No, the graviton does not have a conserved Poincare invariant stress energy tensor. The stress energy tensor is not conserved in GR. Energy is not conserved in GR. Except when you have timelike isometry or when you have an asymptotic flat spacetime (and in the latter only the total energy is conserved, not local energies).